# How can I get this query to work on postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Does anyone know how to adapt this query so that it works in postgresql? the functions add_months doesn't exist apparently. Thank you very much!

```
WITH monthly_activity AS (SELECT date_trunc('month', "Date"::date) AS "month", "Company ID"
FROM "DWH_rollup".appointments_totals)

SELECT last_month."month" + add_months(last_month."month", 1), COUNT(DISTINCT last_month."Company ID")
FROM monthly_activity last_month
JOIN monthly_activity this_month
ON this_month."Company ID" = last_month."Company ID" 
AND this_month."month" = add_months(last_month."month", 1)
WHERE this_month."Company ID" is NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: SELECT last_month.month + INTERVAL '1 month'

Comment: Please review [ask] as this query is basically unsolvable as it stands. Even after resolving the add_months it has major issues that cannot be resolved while retaining the meaning. What is meaning of the first column selected? It is attempting to add timestamps, which cannot be done and would produce nonsense even if it could. Also you have predicates that no rows will ever be returned. The join condition excludes any row where either Company ID is null and then the predicate "and Company ID" is null"  excludes all others. The main question then is: What task are you attempting to solve?

Comment: @Belayer Thanks for your reply. The query is meant to give the churned users per month: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-self-joins-to-calculate-your-retention-churn-and-reactivation-metrics the problem is that the function add_months doesn't exist in postgresql. That is why I asked if someone could help me find a way to get that through another similar function.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks for your reply! I tried that too, the problem is that I can't sum an interval in this case